# Decrypting text in Array format (ie [47, 48, 49]) into original message

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding, encryption

I'm new to Java an I'm making a cipher program in netbeans and have run in to a bit of a snag that either there isn't answer for or I'm just searching for the wrong thing. Now the problem is that I can encrypt my text and display it but I can't decrypt new encrypted text you'll see. Take a look:

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    private void encryptBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)       
    {                                           
        int encryptLength=textToBeEncrypted.getText().length();
        int[] anArray=new int[encryptLength];
        int key=Integer.parseInt((encryptKey.getText())+0);

        if(key<=0)
        {
            decryptTXT.setText(""+"INVALID KEY");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<encryptLength;i++)
            {
                int letter = encryptTXT.getText().toLowerCase().charAt(i);
                int letterCiphered= (letter-key);
                anArray[i]=letterCiphered;
            }

            String output=(Arrays.toString(anArray));
            decryptTXT.setText(output);
        }
    }                                          
}
```

Now lets say the input is `"abc"` and my key is `5` then the output would look exactly like this: `[47, 48, 49]` now how would I get something in the same format (i.e. `[ASCII, ASCII]`) back to the original message? Help would be great and please try to use simple concepts as I only just started coding.

[Edit] I need to know how to do something exactly like this: 
http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/adalal/teaching/f05/107/applets/ascii.html

Comment: If you want to have characters returned that are alphabetical, you had better use a rotational cipher (e.g. ROT-13, where the number 13 is the key). Otherwise you will add a number to 'Z' and get something you had not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Look into line

```
int key=Integer.parseInt((encryptKey.getText())+0);
```

I think there may be problem. You call "encryptKey.getText()" which will probably return a String and then you add '0'.
In Java it will return "YourString+0"
So, if your string is empty, your key will always contain a value of '0'

Comment: The reason for this is so that if no value is entered I can check for if and display an error message. If there's a better way I'd love to implement it.

Comment: Integer.parseInt() already throws a NumberFormatException if the string is not according to "<number>" or "-<number>". You don't have to add the 0. If you want better control on user input, you could catch the (unchecked) NumberFormatException and do something with it (e.g. create a InvalidUserInputException or something, using the NumberFormatException as "cause").

Comment: @Max: this is not really the answer, but it was even worse. If the input is "5" the answer will now be "50". Probably not what was intended. The unnecessary parentheses around encryptKey.getText() make it even harder to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only using characters in the range where this operation is sensible, you can simply declare your `anArray` as a `char[]` instead of `int[]`.

Then you can use `String output = new String(anArray);` to get your result.

(Also, please note that an encryption algorithm similar to your one was already used by Caesar, and is of no practical security value, so please don't use something like this in productive environments.)

Comment: @ChaseVsGodzilla: Java char values are the same as ASCII values (for characters that are actually in the ASCII table). When you did charAt(), you already had ASCII, so you don't need to do any other conversion.